# Loop through cells and concatenate when blank cells are present

Tags: vba

I would like to loop through cells in column A and if a cell is blank perform the CONCATENATE function in column C from column B. I have this code but it is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ConcateBlank()

For i = 3 To 400
    If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
    Cells(i, 3) = CONCATENATE(Cells(i, 2), " ", Cells(i + 1, 2))
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly "not working"?  "ONCATENATE function in column C from column B" - how exactly you want to do that? It's a bit mismatching `CONCATENATE(Cells(i, 2), " ", Cells(i + 1, 2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works without CONCATENATE (maybe faster):

```
Sub ConcateBlank()

For i = 3 To 400
    If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i, 2) & " " & Cells(i + 1, 2)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What is even the difference between `Cells(i + 1, 2)` and `Cells(i, 2)`?

Comment: If i = 1 then Cells(i + 1, 2) is Cells(2, 2) and Cells(i, 2) is Cells(1,2) or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Yeah, no you haven't. I just misunderstood what he was looking for. I blame lack of nutrition. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Hi Dude, yes this is what I was looking however the script only works this way round  :  
Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i + 1, 2) & " " & Cells(i, 2)       as opposed to                 Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i, 2) & " " & Cells(i + 1, 2)    any ideas why it won't this way?  Cheers

Comment: It's Ok I've sorted out the problem. Thank you very much for your help. I am fairly new to VBA so am still finding my way. Thanks again!